# XAML designer gets unhandled exception

Tags: c#, xaml, designer

I have been searching for solution to my problem for a week and no help. 
I'm running VS2015 pro on Windows 10 build 10586. 
My XAML Designer failed to load with following when I created any blank C# universal app.

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException
[5936] Designer process terminated unexpectedly!
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IIsolationDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String assemblyCodeBase, String typeName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

In Event Viewer I got this

```
Faulting application name: XDesProc.exe, version: 14.0.24720.0, time stamp: 0x564ea58d
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632da1c
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000bd8a8
Faulting process id: 0x1a90
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1577281913da3
Faulting application path: C:\Users\incom\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Designer\ShadowCache\15kmnzmb.f2e\g3ow5ih4.vje\XDesProc.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 28fbb682-7d0d-4dd4-8850-5496c96bf41a
Faulting package full name: fbd2dab3-4d5d-4565-9eb7-ae4409ee95fb_1.0.0.0_x86_NorthAmerica_8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: Designer.App
```

I believe there is something wrong with kernel base because when I tried to created a blank C++ universal app and built it, I got a breakpoint pointing to kernelbase.dll.

Plus, I tried many workarounds like deleting shadowcache, reinstalled VS (a few times), change target build but none seems to work for me.

Please help.

Comment: When you tried re-installing VS, did you uninstall the .NET 4.5 runtime as well?

Comment: @Alex I think i didn't. Do you think it is the cause ?